# google.maps.marker position error (nesting google.maps.latLng object in json)

Tags: jquery, json, google-maps-api-3

I receive the following error and can't seem to figure out why a google.maps.latLng object which is nested within some json results in an error, specifically:

**Error: Invalid value for property : (-19.240542583932452, 148.15044705312494)**

Does anyone have any ideas why this code is resulting in the error? When I console.log *json.markers[n].latLng* firebug states it is a google.maps.latLng object, although when it is included as part of the error it is clearly represented as the .toString() output (not sure if that is simply because the error message is a string or not).

I am using the following two methods on a jQuery Google Maps V3 API plugin I have been working on. Here are some snippets, I didn't include the full code as it would only clutter the post. *I hard coded some json for clarity, in my completed plugin it will be retrieved through an ajax call.*

Within the init method of my plugin:

```
    // Request list of markers and return the json object
var markers = methods.requestMarkers();

// Place the markers
methods.placeMarkers(markers);
```

As separate methods:

```
requestMarkers : function () {

    return {"markers":[{"id":["7"],"latLng":[new google.maps.LatLng(-19.240542583932452, 148.15044705312494)]},{"id":["8"],"latLng":[new google.maps.LatLng(-28.0497654, 153.43591700000002)]}]}
},

placeMarkers : function ( json ) {

    if (json.markers.length > 0) {

        var markers = new Array();

        for(var n=0; n < json.markers.length; n++){ 

            markers[n] = new google.maps.Marker({
                map         : methods.map,
                position    : json.markers[n].latLng
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The full code can be found [on Github and is still wip.](https://github.com/Asciant/jquery.location/blob/1.1.0-wip/js/jquery.multiple.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A call of LatLng will always returns a LatLng-object, also when wrong parameters are supplied. 
The argument currently is an array with 1 LatLng-object, so you have to set position to

```
json.markers[n].latLng[0]
```

**Related to the github-code:**
The requestMarkers-function(using the AJAX-code) will not return anything, so markers will not contain the json-response.  Call `placeMarkers()` inside `done()`

```
requestMarkers : function () {

$.ajax({
type: "get",
url: methods.options.ASSOCIATED,
dataType: "json"
}).done(function( json ) {
if (json.markers.length > 0) {
methods.placeMarkers(json);
}
});


     }
```

Comment: Excellent answer, fixed the issue right away. Thank you also for going the extra mile and checking the code on Github! Cheers.